# How can I change the font in Battlefield 3?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3

Ever since I have gotten into DICE games I have notice I can barely read out the names of the guns or just about anything in multiplayer. Is there any way to change the font on the xbox 360 verson of battlefield 3?

Answer (score 5):

No. Unless I'm mistaken, there is no way to change font settings for anything. I'd just use the battlelog to view gun info, since there's not much in the game anyway.